# R: Assign correct date to time of day data

Tags: r, date, time

I have log data files which store only time of day together with some data over several continuous days.

```
       V1       V2
1   11:40:34    1
2   11:52:28    2
3   23:37:19    37
4   23:57:27    38
5   00:17:35    39
6   00:37:43    40
7   00:57:52    41
8   01:18:00    42
9   04:17:03    52
10  17:47:29    18
11  21:29:00    29
12  23:49:58    36
13  00:10:06    37
14  00:30:14    38
15  11:14:39    70
16  18:20:09    1
17  23:28:15    17
18  23:48:24    18
19  00:08:32    19
20  00:28:40    20
21  02:49:38    27
22  08:11:51    43
23  15:14:45    64
24  17:15:34    70
```

I know the "starting date" when the file was created and need to assign the correct date to each row. I figured out a way to do this using a loop:

```
data <- structure(list(V1 = structure(
          c(13L, 14L, 21L, 24L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 
           8L, 10L, 17L, 19L, 23L, 2L, 5L, 
           12L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 1L, 4L, 9L, 
           11L, 15L, 16L), .Label = 
           c("00:08:32", "00:10:06", "00:17:35", 
           "00:28:40", "00:30:14", "00:37:43", "00:57:52", "01:18:00", "02:49:38", 
           "04:17:03", "08:11:51", "11:14:39", "11:40:34", "11:52:28", "15:14:45", 
           "17:15:34", "17:47:29", "18:20:09", "21:29:00", "23:28:15", "23:37:19", 
           "23:48:24", "23:49:58", "23:57:27"), class = "factor"), 
            V2 = c(1L, 2L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 52L, 18L, 29L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
           70L, 1L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 27L, 43L, 64L, 70L)), .Names = 
           c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))

startdate <- as.Date("2010-10-14")
data$day <- startdate
k <- 0

for (i in 1:length(data$V1)-1){
  if (as.POSIXlt(paste(startdate,data$V1[i],sep=" ")) > 
      as.POSIXlt(paste(startdate,data$V1[i+1],sep=" "))) 
      k <- k+1
  data$day[i+1] <- startdate + k
}
```

This gives the desired result, which I can then use to create a proper POSIXlt date column (including date and time).

```
    V1        V2        day
1   11:40:34    1   2010-10-14
2   11:52:28    2   2010-10-14
3   23:37:19    37  2010-10-14
4   23:57:27    38  2010-10-14
5   00:17:35    39  2010-10-15
6   00:37:43    40  2010-10-15
7   00:57:52    41  2010-10-15
8   01:18:00    42  2010-10-15
9   04:17:03    52  2010-10-15
10  17:47:29    18  2010-10-15
11  21:29:00    29  2010-10-15
12  23:49:58    36  2010-10-15
13  00:10:06    37  2010-10-16
14  00:30:14    38  2010-10-16
15  11:14:39    70  2010-10-16
16  18:20:09    1   2010-10-16
17  23:28:15    17  2010-10-16
18  23:48:24    18  2010-10-16
19  00:08:32    19  2010-10-17
20  00:28:40    20  2010-10-17
21  02:49:38    27  2010-10-17
22  08:11:51    43  2010-10-17
23  15:14:45    64  2010-10-17
24  17:15:34    70  2010-10-17
```

I would like to get rid of the loop, though, and would appreciate any ideas on how to do this more "R-style".

Answer (score 2):

A little sloppy, but I think this would get the job done.

```
startdate <- as.Date("2010-10-14")
f=as.POSIXlt(data$V1,format='%H:%M:%S')
x=diff(c(0,which(c(f[-length(f)] > f[-1],T))))
y=rep(seq(x),x)-1
as.POSIXlt(paste(startdate+y,data$V1))
```